# NodeJS | Как оставаться залогиненым после перезахода в браузер?

Tags: node.js, express

Я использую в проекте **express** и **passport** для работы с сессией и все замечательно, исключая одного факта. Регистрация и логин пользователей работает превосходно, но когда пользователь перезаходит в бразуер, то он разлогинивается, потому что наступает другая сессия. Есть ли какая-нибудь хорошая возможность оставаться залогиненым, даже после смены сессии? Должен ли использовать **cookies** или какие либо другие пакеты из **npm**? Используется обычная реализация, с базой данных **mongodb**:

```
app.use(session({
secret:'secret',
maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
httpOnly: true,
cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: null}, 
store: new MongoStore(
    {mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection},
    function(err){
        console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
    })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Был бы признатален, если имеется хороший пример или дельный совет, как решается данная проблема в nodejs.

Правильный вид, надо было всего лишь установить maxAge:

```
app.use(session({
secret:'secret',
maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
httpOnly: true,
cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 3600000}, 
store: new MongoStore(
    {mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection},
    function(err){
        console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
    })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `express-session` нет параметра `maxAge`, есть только `cookie.maxAge`:

```
app.use(session({
secret:'secret',
httpOnly: true,
cookie: {
  path: '/',
  httpOnly: true,
  maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000
},
store: new MongoStore(
    {mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection},
    function(err){
        console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
    })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, **app.configure** относится к старому стилю и сейчас является не желательный. Кукис сервером устанавливается в рамках сессии, но они уничтожаются, когда сессия заканчивается. maxAge: null говорит, чтобы кукис не уничтожался.

Comment: Документация сильно устарела, всё написанное выше неверно. Я разберусь и обновлю ответ актуальной информацией. Если хотите, можете пока помотреть на [проект с настроенной авторизацией](https://github.com/urfu-2015/team5/blob/master/app.js).

Comment: у меня авторизация работает нормально, просто  аккаунт разлогинивается после перезахода в браузер, хотелось бы узнать о путях решения или хотя бы намеки)

Comment: Попробуйте `maxAge` указать.

Comment: В примере, который Вы мне прислали, та же самая проблема, maxAge    тут не влияет ни на что. Нужно сохранять промежуточную информацию на стороне клиента.

Comment: Ну я вот вижу, что `express-session` по умолчанию ставит куку на время сессии. При перезаходе она, естественно, протухает.

Comment: Все верно, а хотелось бы чтобы на стороне клиента оставалась некая информация, чтобы при повторном заходе на сервер, я мог ей воспользоваться для авторизации клиента

Comment: В куке хранится та самая информация -- идентификатор пользователя. Вы попробовали установить время жизни куки?

Comment: Да, поменял и все работает, благодарю. Поставил maxAge: 3600000

Comment: Ура : ) Отметьте ответ как принятый, пожалуйста.

Comment: как будет рейтинг 15, обязательно отмечу!